# Show that $n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ does not converge to $1$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to show that $n^2\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\to 1$ is false?

I have to show that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$ doesn't tend to $e.$

Comment: Well, $(1+1/n)^n$ *does* tend to $e$, so...

Comment: oh no!! $(x_n)^{1/n}\to e>1$ so $x_n\to\infty$

Comment: Does n go to 0 or to infinity?

Comment: Expand $(1+1/n)^n$ and drop all terms except the two lowest order terms. You'll see that $(1+1/n)^n$ is no smaller than $2 $.

Comment: It is somehow easier to prove the second one first and to deduce the first one from it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=-\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\geqslant\frac1{n+1}$$

Comment: I liked it better without the middle step. Thinking of $\log n$ as the area under $y=1/x$ from $1$ to $n$, we see that $$\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right) =\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}x\ge \frac1{n+1}\,.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I agree with your comment. :-))

Answer (score 8):

By Bernoulli's inequality

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} > 1+n^2\frac{1}{n}=1+n$$

Comment: +1. As you can see from my deleted answer, that's the way I prefer. Maybe if you simply invoke the binomial theorem, it will sell better.

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality is a more elementary result than the binomial theorem. It just needs simple induction.

Answer (score 7):

$$ \log( (1 + 1/n)^n ) \to \log(e) = 1$$ So

$$ n^2 \log( 1 + 1/n) = n \log((1 + 1/n)^n) \to \infty$$

Comment: I think this is the slickest one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use Taylor series of  $\ln(1+x)$ at the point $x=0$ and see what you get. Here is the Taylor series

$$ \ln(1+x) = x-{\frac {1}{2}}{x}^{2}+O \left( {x}^{3} \right) . $$

I think it is clear now.

**Added:**

$$\ln( 1+\frac{1}{n} )= \frac{1}{n}-{\frac {1}{2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}+{\frac {1}{2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}-\dots$$

$$ \implies  n^2\ln( 1+\frac{1}{n} )= {n}-{\frac {1}{2}}{}+{\frac {1}{3}}{\frac{1}{n}}-\dots$$

$$ \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\ln( 1+\frac{1}{n} ) = \infty .$$

Answer (score 2):

$$n^{2}\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \sim n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. Since

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}e>2.5$$

there exists $\,M\in\Bbb N\,$ s.t.

$$n>M\;\implies\; \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n>2$$

and thus, for $\,n>M$ :

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}=\left[\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right]^n>2^n\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

$n^2\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ tend to " $\infty \cdot 0$" as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

$\frac{\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}{1/n^2}$ tend to "$\frac{0}{0}$" as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

By L'hopital's rule, the limit is equivalent to the limit of,

$\frac{\left( \frac{-1/n^2}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \right)}{\frac{-2}{n^3}} = \left( \frac{n}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \right)$, which is "$\infty \cdot 1$" $= \infty$.